# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\underline w$ and $\underline t$ two fixed vectors and
$$
T:E_3\longrightarrow E_3, \qquad T(\underline x):=(\underline x\cdot \underline t)\underline w.
$$
Find possible eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$ without solving any secular equation.

**My attempt.** By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if there exists $\underline x\neq0$ such that
$$
T(\underline x)=(\underline x\cdot\underline t)\underline w=\lambda\underline x,
$$
that is $(\underline x\cdot\underline t)\underline w-\lambda\underline x=\underline 0$. But how can I proceed now?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $T$ is not trivial, remark that $w$ and $x$ must be colinear, s $w$ is the unique eigenvector and the eigenvalue is $(w.t)$.

Comment: This need only be true if the coefficients of ${\bf w}, {\bf x}$ in OP's equation are both nonzero. Another possibility is that ${\bf x} \perp {\bf t}$ and $\lambda = 0$ (for any $\bf w$).

Comment: @Travis So, if $\lambda =0$, then the eigenvectors are all $\underline x$ perpendicular to $\underline t$. But if $\lambda\neq0$ (and $(\underline x\cdot\underline t)$ is nonzero), then what are the eigenvectors? Tsemo Aristide wrote "$\underline w$ is the unique eigenvector and the eigenvalue is $(\underline w\cdot \underline t)$", but in my opinion this is not correct...

Comment: Almost. If $\lambda = 0$, then your equation simplifies to $({\bf x} \cdot {\bf t}) {\bf w} = 0$. So, ${\bf w} = 0$ and/or ${\bf x} \perp {\bf t}$. The latter case is what you describe, but the former is possible, too. Tsemo's answer here describes what happens in the generic case, when certain quantities aren't zero.

Comment: @Travis Ok, but I do not understand why Tsemo says "$\underline w$ is the unique eigenvector with eigenvalue $(\underline w\cdot \underline t)$". In my opinion, in the case the coefficients of $\underline w, \underline x$ in the equation are both nonzero, $\underline x$ must be of the type $\underline x=\frac{(\underline x\cdot \underline t)}{\lambda}\underline w$. So $\underline x$ is a multiple of $\underline w$ and there are many eigenvectors...

Comment: It's just informal language, he means the unique eigenvector up to scale (that occurs in this case): If ${\bf x}$ is an eigenvector of any linear transformation, so is $\mu {\bf x}$ for any nonzero scalar $\mu$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $\bf w$ and both coefficients $({\bf x} \cdot {\bf t})$ and $\lambda$ are nonzero, then the identity $({\bf x} \cdot {\bf t}) {\bf w} - \lambda {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ says that $\bf w$ and $\bf x$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: But, by definition of linearly independence, it implies that $(\underline x\cdot\underline t)=\underline \lambda=0$, right?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo---the identity says they are *linearly dependent*. Then, since ${\bf w} \neq {\bf 0}$ in this case, $\bf x$ is a scalar multiple of $\bf w$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\underline w$ and $\underline t$ are both nonzero, otherwise the problem is trivial. $T$ maps *every* input to a scalar multiple of $\underline w$, so the only possibilities for eigenspaces of $T$ are the span of $\underline w$ and the kernel of $T$.

For the first, you have by linearity of the dot product $T(k\underline w)=(k\underline w\cdot\underline t)\underline w = (\underline w\cdot\underline t)(k\underline w)$, which gives you one eigenvalue of $T$ and its corresponding eigenspace.

For the second, since $\underline w\ne 0$, $(\underline x\cdot\underline t)\underline w=0$ iff $\underline x\cdot\underline t = 0$, so the kernel of $T$ consists of all vectors orthogonal to $\underline t$. These are all eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalue zero.